# Replace token in file before building, but keep token in sources

Tags: java, gradle

I want to replace a `@VERSION@` token in a java source file with a version before building (Gradle is my build system of choice).

In my current script `ant.replace(file: 'src/main/java/randers/notenoughvocab/main/Reference.java', token: '@VERSION@', value: version)` it replaces the occurrences of `@VERSION@` in the actual source file, so after a build all occurrences of the pattern have been replaced by the version and if I change the version the the gradle build file it will no longer find any patterns in there and the version will not update.

I have also seen a task [here](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#filterOnCopy), but I do not get what values need to be applied for my specific project.

The project layout for my project, if that is needed:
[image: Screenshot of file layout taken from IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.2, Dark theme]

Comment: My recommendation would be to put the version token in a properties file template, copy the properties file into a target dir replacing the token in the process, then read the properties file in the Java class.  Is there a specific reason the version has to be embedded into the .class file?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You only need to replace `@VERSION@` tokens before releasing your software to the public. Here I defined a task `compileForRelease` that accomplishes it:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

task sourcesForRelease(type: Copy) {
    from 'src/main/java'
    into 'build/adjustedSrc'
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [VERSION: '2.3.1'])
}

task compileForRelease(type: JavaCompile, dependsOn: sourcesForRelease) {
    source = sourcesForRelease.destinationDir
    classpath = sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
    destinationDir = file('build/adjustedClasses')
}
```

I don't recommend messing with standard tasks defined by the Java plugin because that would add unnecessary overhead to each and every build.

Comment: @RAnders00 it's your project - anyway Opal's suggestion is a really weird way to achieve your goal. I wish you had tried the cleaner alternative I suggested in this answer. It's even easier to understand, and you just need to drop ten lines of Groovy code and type `.\gradlew doc`

Comment: @RAnders00 in fact gradlew build should **NOT** touch the working directory (see comments to Opal's answer). The directory adjustedSrc contains source files with token replaced and is then fed to the task doc to generate the javadocs (and you could do the same thing to generate the jar of the .class files)

Comment: The problem in messing with standard tasks (like compileJava) is that you add the replacement overhead **for every build**. Bad practice. Builds should be as fast as possible, and you only need the replacement when releasing (for example later you may add a CI server that may not need the filter step - CPU cycles are scarce resources!)

Comment: @Raffaele The problem with release specific tasks is that you may introduce bugs that only occur in release builds, I would say that is bad practice. Its better to fail early. It would also increase complexity of creating a release.

Comment: Can't understand how your proposal reduces the probability of production bugs, since it's exactly the same transformation. Only difference is that my suggestion preserves the source code

Answer (score 10):

I found existing answers somewhat unsatisfying, so here is my solution:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

task processSource(type: Sync) {
    from sourceSets.main.java
    inputs.property 'version', version
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [VERSION: version])
    into "$buildDir/src"
}

compileJava {
    source = processSource.outputs
}
```

This addresses various concerns as follows:

1. Unlike @Opal's answer, the main source remains unmolested; instead it is staged with modifications to `$buildDir/src` by the `processSource` task, which mirrors the standard `processResources`.
2. Unlike @Gregory Stachowiak's answer, `sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs` remains the default value and there is no sleight of hand in specifying a location that does not (yet) exist
3. Unlike @Raffaele's answer, there is no separate task set for release vs other builds. I disagree that separating them is desirable; I think the added complexity is not worth it unless you have measured any performance hit and found it to be unacceptable. Before going with @Raffaele's solution I would even for instance prefer to limit the scope of the `filter` with include/exclude patterns.
4. Task dependencies are implicitly defined via outputs.
5. All locations are taken from defaults and nothing is stringly typed. The only magic value here is `src`, the directory under `$buildDir` where the processed source files are put.
6. (Edit: added 2019/1/12) Other answers do not properly handle situations where only the version has changed. Changing the version should, by itself, invalidate the task output. This is accomplished via `inputs.property`.
7. (Edit 2019/5/20) Uses `Sync` rather than `Copy` so that files deleted from source are deleted from the filtered source as well (thanks, @Earthcomputer).

Comment: I would use the `Sync` task rather than `Copy` so that it deletes files in `$buildDir/src` that were deleted from `src/main/java`. Other than that, +1, best answer here :)

Comment: Yes, `Sync` is better. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to only work on java source files. Is there a way to do this with any arbitrary file?

Comment: Does this work for Kotlin and Java?

Answer (score 7):

**WARNING: As indicated in comments by @Raffaele filtering source code may result in serious problems. This answer assumes that you know well what are you doing and are conscious about potential problems that may occur.**

The problem is in the fact that java source files are not copied - they're compiled only - in place. So you need to:

1. Before compilation - copy the file that contains `@VERSION@`
2. Filter the file.
3. Compile
4. Restore original file.

Not sure about paths but the following piece of code should be helpful:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

version = '0.0.1'
group = 'randers.notenoughvocab'
archivesBaseName = 'NotEnoughVocab'

def versionFile = 'src/main/java/randers/notenoughvocab/main/Reference.java'
def tempDir = 'build/tmp/sourcesCache'
def versionFileName = 'Reference.java'

compileJava.doFirst {
    copy {
        from(versionFile)
        into(tempDir)
    }
    ant.replace(file: versionFile, token: '@VERSION@', value: version)
}

compileJava.doLast {
    copy {
        from(tempDir + '/' + versionFileName)
        into(project.file(versionFile).parent)
    }
}
```

Comment: @RAnders00, yes I've just written how it should be implemented :)

Comment: **-1: this is conceptually wrong and really dangerous: build tools should never ever touch source files**. Even when sources are in some source control system, when the build fails (or there's a bug in the buildfile) and the working directory is not clean you risk to loose hours (days?) of works **forever**. This post is also dangerous for other users that will come here from Google and will copy and adapt this code in their buildfile without understanding the risks

Comment: @Raffaele, agreed in general. However I don't get this losing the work forever, especially when it comes SCM tools. I wouldn't do it in the way presented - rather use property file, which is a common practice and sometimes version number is needed in code - not in docs only. I just assumed that OP knows what he wants and does.

Comment: OP just wants to replace @VERSION@ before releasing - there's no use in replacing tokens once and then commit. Otherwise what will you do when tagging next version and there are no more @tokens@? The problem here is **how**. When you launch your build in a working copy with local modifications you may loose work. Suppose you spent last three hours working on a heavy refactoring. Before committing you want to build the sources. There's a bug in the buildscript that replaces "set" with "get" in all your .java files. There's no "undo" button here, you simply have lost three hours of work

Comment: Agreed, it does make sense. I may remove the answer it @RAnders00 unaccept it.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem. And I was unable to find working solution. None of the examples I found worked. I believe it might to a fact, that I am new to Gradle and those examples omit some obvious pieces of code. So I looked into Gradle and found my own solution, that I'd like to share:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

// Change compiler source directory
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['build/src/main/java']
        }
    }
}

// Prepare sources for compilation
task prepareSources(type: Copy) {
    from('src/main/java')
    into('build/src/main/java')
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [pluginVersion: version])
}

// Prepare sources, before compile
compileJava {
    dependsOn prepareSources
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Note that I needed to 'rebuild' project though I'm doing slightly different.

Answer (score 3):

To complement other answers, I found this idiom more simple if there's only one value you are looking to change:

```
task generateSources(type: Copy) {
    from 'src/main/java'
    into 'build/src/main/java'
    filter { line -> line.replaceAll('xxx', 'aaa') }
}
```