# How can I modify Java source code in my Gradle project prior to compilation without modifying the files on disk?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a Gradle project. In my source code I have some some annotations (among other things) which take the same string. However, this same string exists in a config file, and I would like to only reference that file, so I only have to change this string in one place in order to change all instances of it. Because of this, I would have to read the string from file, meaning the string isn't compile-time constant. Thus I can't use the string read from the file as an annotation argument.

```
// I have this.
@Annotation("some_string")
Object a;

@Annotation("some_string")
Object b;


// This doesn't work
String ss = // read a file, fetch the string from the file.

@Annotation(ss)
Object a;

@Annotation(ss)
Object b;
```

I was wondering if there was a way within Gradle to modify the source code prior to compilation in a way that allows me to have a single variable control all the annotation arguments.

I.e., in the source code I could have `@Annotation("%%some_string%%")` and replace all occurrences of `%%some_string%%` with the variable in the Gradle task. It would be easy enough to simply modify each source file with something like

```
def annotation_variable = // read a file, fetch the string from the file.
for ( f in srcFileTree ) {
    def text = file(f).text
    file(f).text = text.replaceAll("%%some_string%%", annotation_variable)
}
```

However, that would permanently modify the source file. So, I'm looking for a way to modify the file in the pipeline, without actually modifying the file on disk. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: *I can't simply define a variable and use that variable as the string*: yes, you can. The variable must be a compile-time constant (public static final). But this seems to be what you want anyway.

Comment: @JBNizet ah, good point. I've edited my question to explain why that doesn't work in my situation.

Comment: It's of course possible, but I wouldn't do it that way. Why not put the variable name in the annotation rather than its value, and read the corresponding value from a the resource file at runtime?

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry, I'm not entirely sure what you mean. If you're suggesting having the annotation code read the value from file, then I suppose that is a valid solution, but my example is an oversimplification. I have multiple 3rd party annotations which share this same issue. I would have to extend each one of them and write code to read from the config file for each of them. While not horribly complex, it doesn't scale as well in my workflow as I believe the solution I'm looking for would.

Comment: I still think it would be a better solution, but anyway, if you want to stick with a source preprocessor, then you'll have to create a task that copies and filters your sources to a directory (let's name it "actualSources") under build, and then configure the gradle SourceSet to read from that actualSources directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your java templates in a different directory to your normal java sources (eg `src/template/java`). This will reduce the "work" required by Gradle and will also mean your IDE won't try to compile the templates.

Then add a task to replace tokens in your templates and copy them to a directory under `$buildDir` (so they are deleted via "clean" and also never committed to git)

```
task generateJava(type: Copy) {
   from 'src/template/java'
   into "$buildDir/generated/java"
   filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [someToken: 'someReplacement'])
}
```

Now add the generated directory to the "main" java sourceSet and wire the task into the [DAG](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDir  "$buildDir/generated/java"
compileJava.dependsOn 'generateJava'
```

Assuming your IDE has Gradle integration, your IDE should also now compile the generated sources

See "Filtering files as they are copied" in the [working with files](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html) docs

Comment: Despite not being the solution I used, based on what I've read and my [conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59692381/how-can-i-modify-java-source-code-in-my-gradle-project-prior-to-compilation-with?noredirect=1#comment105540786_59692381) with JB Nizet in the comments of this question, this seems to be the answer which best fits the question. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I answered your request but wasn't convinced it was the best solution. Looking up a property file from the classpath at runtime could solve your issue. There are valid use cases for my solution above, just not yours

Answer (score -1):

You can modify output file instead of source. Example for War task and replaceTokens filter (use your favorite task and filter):

```
tasks.withType(War) { warTask ->
        ...
        from('src/main/java/YOUR_PACKAGE') {
            include YOUR_FILE(s)

            filter ReplaceTokens, beginToken: '@', endToken: '@', tokens: [
                    'YOUR_TOKEN_NAME': YOUR_VALUE
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: @barfuin No, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30038540/replace-token-in-file-before-building-but-keep-token-in-sources)