# How to pass a timestamp property from build.gradle to application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have a timestamp value defined in build.gradle like the following,

**build.gradle**

```
def timestamp = new Date().format('yyyyMMddHHmm')
println "Timestamp:" + timestamp

springBoot {
    mainClass = 'com.example.login.Application'
    buildInfo {
        properties {
            additionalProperties = [
                    'timestamp': "${timestamp}"
            ]
        }
    }
}
.
.
.
```

Now my **build-info.properties** in **build/resources/main/META-INF** looks like this,

```
build.artifact=login
build.group=com.example
build.name=login
build.timestamp=202307111234
```

**application.properties**

```
current.timestamp=@timestamp@
```

I'm trying to retrieve build.time from build-info properties in my **AppFilter.java** class as follows,

```
public class AppFilter {
    @Autowired
    private BuildProperties buildProperties;

    public AppFilter() {
    }

    public void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
       String timestamp = buildProperties.get("build.timestamp");
       System.out.println("Timestamp=>"+timestamp);
       .
       .
       .
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can pass the timestamp property from build.gradle to application.properties, so that current.timestamp will have the timestamp value from my gradle build?

Getting the following error,

**error after debugging**

```
String timestamp = buildProperties[NullPointerException]....
```

I'm new to gradle build. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace token in file before building, but keep token in sources](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30038540/839733)

Comment: no. it didn't help me.

Comment: You forgot to show your attempt at solving the problem, and what didn't work.

Comment: Instead of doing this, you should use the the Spring Boot BuildInfo functionality: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#integrating-with-actuator.build-info. This will give you an object you can inject in your Spring Boot application that will already have the timestamp (`build.time`).

Comment: @GreenSaguaro `BuildInfo` is not what the OP wants or needs. It generates a `META-INF/build-info.properties` which needs to be read by the application, and is nothing like `application.*`.  Build info is primarily meant to be read by Actuator as read-only information.

Comment: @Coder It’d help if you correctly spelled `application.properties`. Your question has been asked and solved a billion times, both in Stackoverflow and outside. Please take the time to research, especially when you’re given a solution already.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar You inject the `BuildProperties` bean wherever you need it. It is not limited to actuators. Let the poster decide what they want and don't want.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, I've updated my question. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it using your own replace:

*build.gradle.kts*

```kotlin
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

tasks.named<ProcessResources>("processResources") {
    filesMatching("application.properties") {
        filter(ReplaceTokens::class, "tokens" to mapOf("current.timestamp" to "abc"))
    }
}
```

I believe in Groovy it would be this:

*build.gradle*

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

tasks.named("processResources", ProcessResources) {
    filesMatching("application.properties") {
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: ["current.timestamp": "abc"])
    }
}
```

With that said, I would suggest using the Spring Boot build info instead:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#integrating-with-actuator.build-info

Once that is in place, you can inject the `BuildProperties` bean to get its values:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/info/BuildProperties.html

*Working Example:*

*build.gradle.kts*

```kotlin
plugins {
    `java-library`
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.+"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
}

springBoot {
    buildInfo {
        properties {
            additional.set(mapOf("timestamp" to "Timestamp: ${Date()}"))
        }
    }
}
```

*Test*

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class BuildInfoTest {
    @Autowired
    BuildProperties buildProperties;

    @Test
    void foo() {
        System.out.println("====================================");
        System.out.println(buildProperties.getName());
        System.out.println(buildProperties.getTime());
        System.out.println(buildProperties.get("timestamp"));
        System.out.println("====================================");
    }
}
```

*Output:*

```
====================================
my-project
2023-07-11T19:55:18.473Z
Timestamp: Tue Jul 11 15:55:18 EDT 2023
====================================
```

Comment: I tried your approach (which also gives the timestamp's updated value i need in build-info.properties everytime i bootrun) and updated my question above. But, right now i'm running into null pointer exception. Any thoughts on that? Thanks!

Comment: @Coder Your null pointer exception is coming when you try to use the `BuildProperties` class?

Comment: Yes. That's correct

Comment: @Coder You need to use a different property name other than `time`. The `BuildProperties` already has a property called `time` that it tries to convert to an `Instant`. If this value cannot be converted to an `Instant`, it will remain null. Simply rename your custom property to `timestamp`, or anything else, and you will not get a null.

Comment: Answer updated with a working example.

Comment: I updated build.gradle and tried your test snippet. Still getting NullPointerException for BuildProperties. Seems like there's a problem with @Autowired annotation. Any suggesstions as to what might be happening?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254454/discussion-between-greensaguaro-and-coder).

Answer (score 0):

Change your CopySpec to `expand(timestamp: timestamp)`
And change your properties file to `current.timestamp=$timestamp`

The key in the Map passed to `expand()` should be the token that you want replaced.

The `@timestamp@` style of tokens work with the `ReplaceTokens` filter, which you can also use if you prefer. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:filtering_files for details.

Comment: I've updated my question with new info. Any thoughts on that?